# Mi controlador no recibe mi archivo C# (mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

he intendado subir archivos(xlsx) desde la vista al controlador pero siempre que veo que recibe mi controlador, siempre es null, ya he intentado varias formas, solo con formulario, con ajax y el FormData o fetch y FormData, intentando recibir HttpPostedFileBase o usando NPOI y nada, alguien sabe que este pasando?

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo"/>
    <button type="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

(El js)

```
$("button").click(function () {
        var selectFile = ($("#archivo"))[0].files[0];

        var archivo = new FormData();
        archivo.append("fileUpload", selectFile);

        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("subir","contratos")',
        type: "Post",
            data: archivo,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async:false,
        success: function (data) {
            
        },

        error: function (data) {

        }

        });
    });
```

(Mi controlador)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult subir(HttpPostedFileBase archivo)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo ayudar con esto:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult subir(IFormFile archivo))
    {

         if (archivo == null || archivo.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("Archivo no seleccionado.");
    }

    var rutaArchivo = Path.GetTempFileName();
    
    using (var stream = new FileStream(rutaArchivo, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await archivo.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    // Aca le podes poner lo que quieras hacer con el archivo.
   

    return Ok("Archivo subido correctamente.");
    }
```